# Группировка данных в Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Есть dataframe

```
                tr_datetime mcc_code tr_type  amount       term_id
    customer_id                 
    39026145    0 10:23:26  4814     1030   -2245.92       NaN
    39026128    1 10:19:29  6011     7010   56147.89       NaN
    39026145    1 10:20:56  4829     2330   -56147.89      NaN
    39026130    1 10:39:54  5499     1010   -1392.47       NaN
    39026145    2 15:33:42  5499     1010   -920.83        NaN
```

В качестве индекса установлены ID пользователя, каждому пользователю соответсвует несколько значений в колонке amount. На выходе хочу получить таблицу со списками ID и соответствующие ему значение столбца amount. На примере приведённой таблице, результат должен быть следующий:

```
39026145: [-2245.92, -56147.89, -920.83]
39026128: [56147.89]
39026130: [-1392.47]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - сделать так:

```
>>> df.groupby('customer_id')['amount'].agg(list)
```